# Trying to access the last element in a var

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the last element in a Var with the following code but it keeps telling me that it is undefined and I can't figure out why.

```js
valueCalculate=valueCalculate+currentValue
var length=valueCalculate.length;
console.log(length);
console.log(valueCalculate[length]);
```

Comment: Please show your some more code

Comment: does the `console.log(length)` also say undefined?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

The last element has index as length -1
So you should get it as:

```
console.log(valueCalculate[length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `length-1` as the index for the last element. This is because in javascript (and many other programming languages) arrays start counting from `0`.

For example, if your `valueCalculate` was `[1, 2, 3, 4]` then your indexes for this array would look like so:

```
// Indexes:  0  1  2  3
            [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So the `length` of your array is `4` as it has 4 elements, but it ends at index `3`. Thus, the last element in your array (or last character in a string for that matter) will always be at the index `length-1`.

See example below:

```js
valueCalculate = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var length=valueCalculate.length;
console.log("length: " + length);
console.log("last: " + valueCalculate[length-1]); // change to length-1
```